# Run node server and webpack together using package.json

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have completed todo app by learning from this video:

[**Super MEAN Stack Tutorial: Angular, Node/Express, Webpack, MongoDB, SASS, Babel/ES6, Bootstrap**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Sbau-oE37w)

In that video at time 19:18 at [this](https://youtu.be/6Sbau-oE37w?t=1158) url it is taught that I should use the below two commands in seperate git-bash instances if I want to run it in **windows** using npm run dev:

```
node server
webpack-dev-server --progress --colors
```

But in Linux (or any other OS than windows) you can use this script:

```
"Scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src node server",
    "dev": "npm start & webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"
}
```

So, Is there any way I can do the  same in windows?

Also, In that tutorial I can see that port no. 3000 is assigned to node server, but due to using dev dependencies he runs the localhost:8080 in browser. You can see that [here](https://youtu.be/6Sbau-oE37w?t=1282). After the tutorial finishes, I followed along and created that app. Now I would like to deploy it. So, I would first like to learn to run test my site in non-dev dependencies mode. i.e. when I type localhost:3000 in browser, my app should run successfully. So, can anybody explain the steps for that?

**Update:**

I am a newbie in node.js. I watched many videos on node and tried to learn something from that. In all the videos I see that I run node server on port no. 3000 and then I type localhost:3000 in my browser. Now lastly I watched video about mean stack in which he uses webpack. Now, I am confused. I think there are two servers running. first server is webpack's server and second server is node's server. Upto today I typed localhost:3000 in my browser because I mentioned that port 3000 will be used by node in my code. But now in the video he is running localhost:8080 in browser. It means webpack's server is used. Then what happened to node server. Why can't I just run localhost:3000? Also in the video it is explained that webpack is a dev dependency. So, I think after the app is completed and ready to be deployed, my project can be run on the node server (by making some changes to the code, I am not sure). Let's take an example. Now I don't want to deploy the app to a real server. I want the same app to run on my friend's pc. He is not a developer. So, he should not depend on webpack as webpack is a dev dependency. So, he should be able to run the app on node server instead of webpack's server. So, he should type localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8080. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's break this down:

1. If you've defined this script:

   ```
   "Scripts": {
       "start": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src node server",
       "dev": "npm start & webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"
   }
   ```
2. ... then this npm command: `npm run dev`
3. ... actually invokes these two actions:

   a) `npm start &`  # Runs NPM in the background

   b) `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors` # Concurrently runs webpack in the foreground

You can accomplish the same thing in many ways using Windows, starting with a simple .bat file like this:

4. EXAMPLE: RunDev.bat:

   ```
   start npm start
   webpack-dev-server --progress --colors
   ```

=======================================================================

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1. Please forget about watching videos for a few moments.  Try a couple of "hello world" tutorials.  More importantly, play with the actual code.  Try changing things in the code, and see what happens.
2. Forget about webpack, at least for the moment.
3. Think of npm as a "build tool"; *not* as a way to run your application.  At least for a moment.
4. Focus on "node".  Write a "node application".
5. Part of your "node application" will require "ExpressJS" and "Jade" (now renamed "pug" - I'm still using "Jade").  Use npm to get your ExpressJS and Jade dependencies, but stay focussed on Node.

SUGGESTED TUTORIAL:

[A Simple Website in Node.js, Ben Gourley](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-node-js-2016-edition)

6. Be sure to:

a. Download the code

b. Work through the tutorial, using the downloaded code

Please post back (a new post) with any specific questions you might have as you work through  the tutorial.

Comment: PS: to your additional question: if you want webpack to run on port 3000, then simply add "--port NN" to your command: `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 3000`

Comment: If I try those scripts in git-bash on windows: I get the following error: 'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I am actually not interested in port numbers. But I would like to transform this project to an electron app. So, I asked for a single command and the port numbers.

Comment: Also, I would like to ask that if my app is completed, then why should I care for dev dependencies? Can't I just run npde server without webpack. This is what I would like to actually ask.

Comment: Your original question was actually "Q: how do I run a background job (`&`) in Windows?"  One answer is to use `start` in a Windows .bat file.  Then you say "Gee, I'm using git-bash".  And you complain about an error that wouldn't nave occurred if you use the .bat file I suggested.  You updated your post to ask about port #'s, then you say you don't care about port#s.  You're using webpack, then you say you don't want to use webpack.  What *DO* you want????

Comment: Let me clear your confusion. I am a newbie in node.js. I watched many videos on node and tried to learn something from that. In all the videos I see that I run node server on port no. 3000 and then I type localhost:3000 in my browser. Now lastly I watched video about mean stack in which he uses webpack. Now, I am confused. I think there are two servers running. first server is webpack's server and second server is node's server. Upto today I typed localhost:3000 in my browsser because I mentioned that port 3000 will be used by node in my code. Continued in next comment...

Comment: But now in the video he is running localhost:8080 in browser. It means webpack's server is used. Then what happened to node server. Why can't I just run localhost:3000? Also in the video it is explained that webpack is a dev dependency. So, I think after the app is completed and ready to be deployed, my project can be run on the node server (by making some changes to the code, I am not sure). Continued in next comment...

Comment: Let's take an example. Now I don't want to deploy the app to a real server. I want the same app to run on my friend's pc. He is not a developer. So, he should not depend on webpack as webpack is a dev dependency. So, he should be able to run the app on node server instead of webpack's server. So, he should type localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8080. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I have completed 10 projects in node, express and mongo-db. Then I came across mean stack which lead me to that video. But in those 10 projects I was not introduced to webpack. And when I learnt every good techniques from that video, I came across the issue I spotted.

Comment: If you've "done 10 projects in node and express" then you should know that all you need to do is specify "3000" (or 8080, or whatever you want) in your "app.listenI)".  Based on your questions, it sounded like you DIDN'T know that, hence the tutorial recommendation.  It IS a good tutorial - and it might answer some of the other questions you're having.

Comment: No matter what the port number I specify in node app.listen, I have to open localhost:8080 in my browser to run my app in browser. That's exactly what I am trying to explain you. So, isn't there a way of getting rid of running webpack server every time I run my app?

Comment: If you start a Node/Express app that sets `app.list(3000)` ... then you should be able to point your browser to l`http://localhost:3000`.  Correct? Q: Isn't that what you want?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, I specified app.listen(3000). Still, I am not able to point my browser to http://localhost:3000. If I do so, I get an error in console saying `Unexpected token <` in file bundle.js line no.1. But If I point my browser to http://localhost:8080, I don't get any errors and my app works perfectly fine.

Comment: Q: did you follow my advice to FORGET about webpack and focus EXCLUSIVELY on Node/Express (at least for the moment)?

Comment: Yes, of course I have done that. That's a very simple tutorial.

Comment: I dunno, dude.  It sounds like you're still using Webpack.  It sounds like Webpack is where the 8080 is coming from.  And it sounds like "bundle.js" is probably a Webpack file.  Just sayin'...

Comment: Yes you are right about that. bundle.js is a webpack file and 8080 is coming from webpack. That is in my mean stack app. But in the sample node app from tutorial that you linked in your answer I can run on 3000 or any port given in node server code.

Comment: what is the === condescending section that no one needs?