# Integrate NodeJS MySql with React Application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have a normal `React` App which runs on `Node` Server

```
-node_modules
-src
   -Actions
   -Components
   -Stores
   -Server
     -server.js
-package.json
```

Basically when i run `npm start` `React App` will run and for suppose i will be able to see the example in `localhost:8080`

Now my `server.js` file includes `MySql` code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "yourusername",
    password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I have to explicitly run `node server.js`  command to get the connection to `mysql` and run the queries their.

How do i integrate `server.js` command in my React App, so that when i run `npm start`, my `MySql` connection and the file should execute

Comment: With `npm start`, you might be using `webpack-dev-server` then, am I right?

Comment: So then change the `start` script in package.json to `"start": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src node server",`.  That will call your node server and it will work then.

Comment: you can add `node server` in your npm scripts using `&&` operator like this   `"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config './webpack/webpack.config.js' && node server"
  }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817917/run-node-server-and-webpack-together-using-package-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer is:** you don't. 
**The short fix is:** use some kind of program to help you start both (like npm)

**The long answer is:**

Set up your npm start task to run both of them. You can do this with [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). (`npm install --save concurrently`)

Change your npm start task (in your package.json) to something like this:

```
"start": "concurrently -k -r -s first \"node server.js\" \"webpack-dev-server""
```

If you need further assistance please share your package.json file.

**The longest answer is:**

*This part is OPTIONAL, only follow it if you want to LEARN.*

If you want more details you could look at a somewhat more advanced project such as my [react-sane-starter](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/react-sane-starter) to get an idea how to efficiently start multiple services. This project also contains Docker if you're interested.

**concurrently over &**

People often suggest to run one of the tasks in the background using &, this will usually prevent logs being shown (unless redirected), I'd highly recommend using concurrently to solve this issue. (it will prefix your different services quite nicely)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for explaining these things.

Comment: No problem, enjoy!